# How to pass ID parameter to views.py in CreateView in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am doing a web app containing products with a Rating (1-5) functionality. I created an app called rating and I want people to click on a button "rate" on single.html which will direct you to a rating page(form.html) where people will be rating and then re-redirect you to the single.html after submitting the rate.

The issue here is that I do not know how to pass the product ID to the Rating(CreateList) in views.py.

so far I've done:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^product/(?P<product_id>\d+)/rating/$', views.RatingView.as_view, name = 'rating'),]
```

models.py

```
class Rating(models.Model):

RATING_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Poor'),
    (2, 'Average'),
    (3, 'Good'),
    (4, 'Very Good'),
    (5, 'Excellent')    
)
productID = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
indRating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)

def __str__(self):
    return self.productID
```

views.py

```
class RatingView(CreateView):
model = Rating
fields = ['productID', 'indRating']

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(RatingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['product_id'] = self.kwargs['product_id']
    return context
```

Comment: A bit unclear what you are asking. Do you need to create an appropriate link in the template? `{% url "rating" product_id=product.pk %}` or the like will do.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks for your interest!
Yes I want to direct the user to a new page which is form.html after the user has clicked on "rate" button. What I am asking is that in my Views.py, how to I pass the product ID parameter so that I can have the url to be like stated in my urls.py above.

Comment: hi jason, i don't understand what you want. tell me the process of rating again please because i think i can help you :D

Comment: @mohammedqudah Hi Mohammed, thanks for your interest!

So I am doing a web app selling some products. And each product has their product page of their own called single.html. On that page, I've put a button called "Rate Product" which will direct the user to a page called form.html where they will do the rating. The rating will be from 1-5 and the user will click submit which will redirect them to the product page. I want to have the url stated above as the single.html page. My problem is in views.py, I can't seem to pass the productID as parameter in createview class.

Comment: So you don’t know how to handel the url parameter in th ecreateview?

Comment: @mohammedqudah Yes exactly!

Comment: you can - for example -  in the `get_context_data` get the url parameter, but i mean the post/get parameter like `?key=value&key=somevalue` by using `self.request.GET.get('key')` or if you want to use the `<key>[0-9]` you can override the `__init__` function in the create view

Comment: @mohammedqudah thank you! I did something like this and it solved.